# What is the most terse way of reading single keystrokes up to one specific key?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, io-monad

I had written the simple program below, convinced it would absorb all keystrokes I hit and, when I hit <kbd>q</kbd>, it would print the previous keys as a single string.

```hs
import System.IO
main = do
  hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
  hSetEcho stdin False
  x <- takeWhile (/= 'q') <$> sequence (repeat getChar)
  print x
```

But that's not the case.

It's not that keys are not read, as it's obvious when I change the longest line to

```hs
  x <- takeWhile (/= 'q') <$> sequence (repeat (getChar >>= \c -> print c >> return c))
```

which does print the characters one by one as I type them; but the <kbd>q</kbd> doesn't cause the loop to exit.

My understanding is that `sequence` is not lazy, in the sense that it will try to run the infinite list of `getChar` actions before `takeWhile` has a chance to start its job.

If that's the case, then what other options do I have?

If the intent is clear form the snippet above, I can add that in the real application `getChar` would be swapped with a function that `do`es `c <- getChar` and then makes a processing on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider a little helper action for that purpose:

```
getInput :: Char -> IO Char
getInput previous = do
  c <- getChar
  if c == 'q' then return previous else getInput c
```

This would enable you to get `x` like

```
x <- getInput ' '
```

or with some other appropriate default value instead of `' '`.

If you truly want a one-liner, you can always use `fix` to convert any recursive action into a lambda expression.

First, then,

```
import Data.Function
```

and then

```
x <- (fix $ \rec previous -> getChar >>= \c -> if c == 'q' then return previous else rec c) ' '
```

Comment: Thanks, this gave me another idea: `getInput` can actually be _the_ action that reads the input _and_ processes it; in that case, it can just be of type `IO ()` and be defined as  `getAndProcInput = getChar >>= \c -> unless (c == 'q') getAndProcInput`.